# Are Block-Level Boxes Enclosed in Line Boxes?

Tags: html, css, w3c

Is there somewhere in the W3C spec, that specifies that *block-level boxes* get surrounded in *line boxes* automatically?

**Background**

As we know, [vertical padding and border of *inline boxes* do not affect *line box* height](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced). *Line box* height, in turn, is the only feature of *inline boxes* that affects position of subsequent content. This, in turn, implies that padding / border on *inline boxes* will bleed onto surrounding content.

Quote from W3C CSS 2.1, [Chapter 10](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#leading):

> Although margins, borders, and padding of non-replaced elements do not
>   enter into the *line box* calculation, they are still rendered around
>   *inline boxes*. This means that if the height specified by `line-height`
>   is less than the content height of contained boxes, backgrounds and
>   colors of padding and borders may "bleed" into adjoining *line boxes*.

Note how it says: "bleed into adjoining ***line boxes***".

I did a test and noticed that it does in fact also bleed into adjoining *block-level boxes*.

```css
.one {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.two {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.three {
  line-height: normal;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="one">test</div>
  
  <span class="two">
    <span class="three">test two</span>
    x
  </span>
```

Therefore, I was wondering, does it say anywhere in the spec that *block-level boxes* are also surrounded by *line boxes*? I could only find relevant *line box* details under [inline formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#inline-formatting), within which only *inline-level boxes* participate.

Thank you.

Comment: Following the link, CSS2, 2011-06-07… What about today?

Comment: One spec I found says that a line box is one line of text inside a block box, which means that a line box by definition cannot contain a block box. I've yet to find a more up to date definition than 2007 though.

Comment: Anyway, to answer the question, my guess is that the quote means the  background colors and such may "bleed" into the line box that follows, which is either the first line box of the next adjoining block box or the next line box in the parent block box. It does not mean that there is a line box around the current block box.

Comment: @MrLister Unfortunately it does not specify anywhere that block-level boxes (i.e. block boxes, because they are also block container boxes) contain line boxes (unless, of course, they contain only inline-level boxes, in which case they establish an inline formatting context and would contain line boxes as specified in CSS 2.1). The observed behaviour shows that the bleed happens for padding / border of all inline boxes (note: not atomic inline-level boxes), regardless of the type of box above / below it in the normal flow.

Comment: @Takit Isy: CSS2.1 became a W3C Recommendation on 2011-06-07. Nothing has changed since then, not even in the work-in-progress CSS2.2, and there isn't a CSS3 spec for line-height, so CSS2 remains the definitive reference for line-height.

Comment: @Mr Lister: A reference for that can be found in the spec in the "inline formatting context" link in the question. Cross-reference with [§9.2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#block-boxes), which, as Magnus has pointed out, says "A block container box either contains only block-level boxes or establishes an inline formatting context and thus contains only inline-level boxes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not actually sure if a block-level box can be said to be adjoining to a line box (or vice versa). However, in your example, there are in fact two line boxes — one that is generated by `div.one` when formatting its inline contents by establishing an inline formatting context, and another that is generated by the `body` element when formatting `span.two` (and its `span.three` child) — and the line box inside `div.one` *can* be said to be adjoining to the one containing `span.two` and `span.three`.

For the purposes of drawing inline boxes, it doesn't matter which block container is generating each line box that's adjoining to those containing those inline boxes. It doesn't even matter whether any of the block containers also establishes a block formatting context. That is why you see the inline box of `span.three` bleed into the line box inside `div.one`.

A block-level box cannot directly coexist with a line box, and by definition of "block-level" it cannot be enclosed in a line box either (to answer your title). In your example, the line box on which the `span`s are rendered resides in an [anonymous block box](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level) that is then laid out as a sibling of the `div`. That anonymous block box establishes its own inline formatting context for the `span`s, just like the `div` does for its text.

Comment: but the real question is : what should we do when we have a headache after reading this? :/

Comment: @Temani Afif: The second paragraph tells you all you need to know :) OK that and the first sentence in the third paragraph...

Comment: BoltClock and @TemaniAfif, I am getting close to mastering all this, thanks to the many solid answers by the two of you. Thank you. Basically, whenever we have "runs of text" (i.e. text meant to be rendered), it's enclosed in an anonymous box: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#anonymous. My only question here is: If we remove the run of text in div one ("test"), and just set a w/h on the block-level box, then there will be no inline formatting context there (only a block formatting context). Thus, there will be no line box. Should it then still bleed over onto that box?

Comment: @Magnus: Yes, in much the same way it bleeds over any background. An empty box can be considered part of some element's background - the borders and padding of inline boxes will bleed over just about anything, really.

Comment: Which is a bit odd to me, because according to the quote from the spec (see OP), it only bleeds over `line boxes`...

Comment: @Magnus: I think that sentence is meant to describe what happens to surrounding line boxes when inline box dimensions exceed line box height. I can see why it could be interpreted to mean that this bleeding behavior is defined only for line boxes, however...

Comment: One last question if I may: Is there any point in using this seemingly newer version of the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/ ? It has this newer definition of the box model as well: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/

Comment: @Magnus: css-position-3 is in active development and well worth paying attention to. Most of the existing behavior in CSS2 is unchanged, though. css3-box is in the process of being rewritten and you don't have to worry about it for the most part. That particular TR is abandoned, but [even the ED hasn't been updated in over a year and a half](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box).